# Nested flex container changing alignment of surrounding elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was fiddling around with flexbox, and I noticed something odd.

Even though CHILD 1 is not within the flexbox, the position of the entire `.child` element shifts because `.centervert` has a vertical flexbox:

```css
#cont {
  background: blue;
}

.centervert {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">

  <div class="child">
    CHILD 1
  </div>

  <div class="child ">
    <div class="centervert">
      CHILD 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3ymxhe8/2/:

If you comment out `display: flex`, the CHILD elements appear side by side as expected. But with the flex display, CHILD1 is shifted down, to align with the contents of .centervert.

What gives?

Comment: It's not because of displaying it as flex. It's because you have specified justify-content as center that the first div shifts down. Comment that and check.

Comment: I wanted the content of CHILD2 to be centered vertically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set the display to flex of child 2 and centered the text vertically, you caused child 1 to adjust itself according to its default vertical-align property, which for inline elements is baseline. You can set the vertical align property of child1 (as well as child2) to something like top or middle instead, which will remove the gap.

```css
#cont {
  background: blue;
}
.centervert {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="child">
    CHILD 1
  </div>
  <div class="child ">
    <div class="centervert">
      CHILD 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *When you set the display to flex of child 2 and centered the text vertically, you caused child 1 to adjust itself according to its default vertical-align property...* Can you explain that? It was already subject to the `baseline` value before flex and centering were called. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Michael_B Prior to child 2 being set to flex and having the text vertically centered with justify-content: center, its text would be at the top of the div the same way child 1's is and they would be lined up without any gaps as both baselines would already be aligned.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. The key is to always watch the actual text. I was focusing on the inline-level box. If you play around with `justify-content`, using `flex-start`, `center`, `flex-end`, you'll see that the text in both boxes always aligns to `baseline`. Thanks for enlightening me.